# Macbook pro early 2013 throws contents RAM away

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, memory, filevault, encryption

I have a MacBook Pro early 2013, running OSX mavericks and filevault(encryption) is enabled.

After a (I suspect) update, the locking behavior has been different. When the screen gets locked (manually or automatically) all running programs die. Including but not limited to spotify(while playing music), Time Machine(while in the middle of a backup, getting interrupted), Transmission(while downloading torrents).

It is not suspend-to-disk either, because all programs reinitialize when I unlock the macbook. Some programs do not properly save state, so this is really annoying.

The previous behavior was regular lock screen with a screensaver, suspend to RAM after a certain time has passed. Which worked fine for me. I do realize that Apple probably tries to prevent DMA attacks this way, but for me it is really an overkill at the cost of usability. The main reason for enabling filevault is burglary. burglars do not have the expertise to extract the encryption key from RAM anyway.

Is there a way to re-enable the old behavior(suspend-to-ram) without disabling filevault?

ps: I am assuming this new behavior is because of filevault, I have not been able to test this, because disabling filevault is not an option for me.

Answer (score 2):

I have been able to test and this new behavior is not due to file vault. What you can do is in System Preference>Energy Saver set the display sleep to whatever you had the computer sleep at before that way the screen will turn off but all programs will keep going. Next go to System Preference>Security & Privacy and set "Require Password" to Immediately. Other than changing any shortcuts you have to lock the screen to turning the screen off then your computer will basically go to sleep keeping all programs running but you still need a password to get back in. Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow, that's kinda a dirty workaround. I tried it anyway, and sadly, I must inform you that it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

**I will answer my own question here.**

The following procedure solved my problem:

1. Turn off Filevault. Wait for the decryption proces to finish.
2. Reboot MacBook
3. Turn on Filevault. Wait for the eecryption proces to finish.

Now the normal locking behavoir is in place again. I am clueless about why this worked.

Comment: The macbook has reverted to its old behavior again. So this clearly is not a good solution.